# What command should I use in finding the latest version of libgtk in linux

Tags: linux, gtk, apt-get, locate

I need to install libgtk in Ubuntu linux.

I tried to use "sudo apt-get install libgtk", but the answer is that libgtk can't be found in the libgtk package.

How can I use a Linux command to find the latest version of libgtk?

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to FIND a gtk that's already installed on your box, try `locate libgtk` (if you have gnu slocate installed and running) or `find / -name "libgtk*.so*"` and be prepared to wait a while.

The suggestion to search using `aptitude search` or `apt-cache search` will probably do what you need if you're trying to determine how to INSTALL libgtk. Chances are you should have run `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev`.

Comment: Great Thks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
aptitude search libgtk
```

or

```
apt-cache search libgtk
```

to search for package names containing `libgtk`. Availability of aptitude depends on Ubuntu version, but it can be easily installed by apt-get if not found; apt-cache is probably always available.

Which libgtk package you need can't really be decided by the information you provide, so please clarify if you need further help.

Comment: Then which information should I count on to install with "sudo apt-get install libgtk?" should I use pkg-config ? how do I use that?

Comment: `apt-cache search` will return a list of packages that use/are libgtk.  You `apt-get install` one of them.